# Filter out unique Data in Key Value Datastructure in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, key-value

I want to filter my Input Data with "uniqBy". I am new to typescript and don't have an idea how to achieve it. I know i have to loop over each sublist and make the uniqby for each element (data1, data2). This is my input Data below:

```
const data = [
     {
       data1: [
                {
                 id: "1",
                 label: "ONE",
                 anotherId: "3",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                },
                {
                 id: "2",
                 label: "ONE",
                 anotherId: "33",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                },
                {
                 id: "3",
                 label: "TWO",
                 anotherId: "11",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                },
              ]
      },
        data2: [
                {
                 id: "4",
                 label: "ONE",
                 anotherId: "3",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                },
                {
                 id: "5",
                 label: "TWO",
                 anotherId: "33",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                }
               ]
     ]
```

I want to filter my Data, so that i have in each list data1 & data2 only unique information based on the "label" of each item inside these groups.

I want something like:

```
...
map(data => {
  const grouped = groupBy(item => item.group, data);

  const uniq = uniqBy( ... );

  return uniq;
})
...

const uniqByLabel = [
     {
       data1: [
                {
                 id: "1",
                 label: "ONE",
                 anotherId: "3",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                },
                {
                 id: "3",
                 label: "TWO",
                 anotherId: "11",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_One",
                },
              ]
      },
        data2: [
                {
                 id: "4",
                 label: "ONE",
                 anotherId: "3",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_Two",
                },
                {
                 id: "5",
                 label: "TWO",
                 anotherId: "33",
                 mygroupId: 1,
                 group: "Group_Two",
                }
               ]
     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your data structure with help of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy). I assume here, you mean lodash `uniqBy`, because you mentioned its exact name. A `uniqBy` version without lodash would also be fairly easy to implement with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (see sample down under for inspiration). So let's take your example:

```
const res = uniqBy(x => x.label, data[0].data1);
```

will filter one of your sub array for unique entries with `label` discriminator (first item wins). Presumed, the data structure can possibly contain multiple values and remains otherwise akin to your sample, you can code it like this:

```
const newData = data.map((d, idx) =>
  // make Object.keys typed by assertion
  (Object.keys(d) as Array<keyof typeof data[number]>).reduce(
    (acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [cur]: uniqBy(x => x.label, d[cur])
    }),
    // keep same type as each top array item
    {} as typeof data[number]
  )
);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57754834-9tilk)

Full example (I am using the [functional version of lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) here):

```
import uniqBy from "lodash/fp/uniqBy";

const data = [
  {
    data1: [
      {
        id: "1",
        label: "ONE",
        anotherId: "3",
        mygroupId: 1,
        group: "Group_One"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        label: "ONE",
        anotherId: "33",
        mygroupId: 1,
        group: "Group_One"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        label: "TWO",
        anotherId: "11",
        mygroupId: 1,
        group: "Group_One"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data2: [
      {
        id: "4",
        label: "ONE",
        anotherId: "3",
        mygroupId: 1,
        group: "Group_One"
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        label: "TWO",
        anotherId: "33",
        mygroupId: 1,
        group: "Group_One"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const res = data.map((d, idx) =>
  (Object.keys(d) as Array<keyof typeof data[number]>).reduce(
    (acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [cur]: uniqBy(x => x.label, d[cur])
    }),
    {} as typeof data[number]
  )
);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<pre>
  ${JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)}
</pre>
`;
```